# Simple custom User Control clone its values to various other elements on Frame.GoBack()

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, navigation

I was recently working on a user control, let's name it TestUserControl, and used two of its instances on one page.
While I was testing, I noticed, that when I type something into the values of upper TestUserControl, go to another page then go back to the first page - the second instance of TestUserControl is filled with values that had been typed into the first one (and even elements which are not part of user control of type TestUserControl are affected!).

[Here are the screenshots of described behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJtk6.jpg) .

And the code of a simple project from which this screenshots come:

Landing page:

```
<Page x:Class="PageNavigation.Pages.Landing"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageNavigation.Pages"
      xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PageNavigation.Controls"
      xmlns:n="clr-namespace:PageNavigation"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      d:DesignHeight="200"
      d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Landing">

    <Grid Background="White"
          ButtonBase.Click="Grid_Click">

        <WrapPanel Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Margin="0 25"
                       Text="I am a simple text block" />
            <n:NavButton Text="Accounts"
                         ImageSource="/Images/Accounts.png"
                         NavUri="/Pages/Accounts.xaml" />
            <n:NavButton Text="Bills"
                         ImageSource="/Images/Billing.png"
                         NavUri="/Pages/Bills.xaml" />
            <n:NavButton Text="Employees"
                         ImageSource="/Images/Employees.png"
                         NavUri="/Pages/Employees.xaml" />
            <n:NavButton Text="Setting"
                         ImageSource="/Images/Settings.png"
                         NavUri="/Pages/Setting.xaml" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="User controls:" />
                <controls:TestUserControl Width="150"/>
                <controls:TestUserControl Width="150"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace PageNavigation.Pages
{
    public partial class Landing : Page
    {
        public Landing()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Grid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource is not NavButton ClickedButton)
                return;

            NavigationService.Navigate(ClickedButton.NavUri);
        }
    }
}
```

My testing user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PageNavigation.Controls.TestUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageNavigation.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <TextBox/>
            <TextBox/>
            <TextBox/>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <ToggleButton>Toggle me!</ToggleButton>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace PageNavigation.Controls
{
    public partial class TestUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public TestUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Navigation button to another pages (these one with images):

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace PageNavigation
{
    public class NavButton : ButtonBase
    {
        static NavButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NavButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NavButton)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(NavButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(NavButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NavUriProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NavUri", typeof(Uri), typeof(NavButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public Uri NavUri
        {
            get { return (Uri)GetValue(NavUriProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NavUriProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

One of example pages which contains back button:

```
<Page x:Class="PageNavigation.Pages.Employees"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageNavigation.Pages"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      d:DesignHeight="450"
      d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Employees">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Button Content="Back"
                Padding="3"
                Command="NavigationCommands.BrowseBack"
                BorderThickness="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="5,5,0,0" />
        <Label Content="Employees"
               FontSize="50"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace PageNavigation.Pages
{
    public partial class Employees : Page
    {
        public Employees()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Main window:

```
<Window x:Class="PageNavigation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageNavigation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Source="/Pages/Landing.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;

namespace PageNavigation
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();         
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using for the navigation System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService and Frame, which seems to be important, as I couldn't reproduce this bug in a simple application that uses switching ContentControl and custom NavigationService.

When I use binding to view model in TestUserControl values, the problem seems to disappear, but what if I do not need binding, because I use elements of control to manage its internal behavior only - using for example toggle button to hide/show content of a text box field?

I was looking for an explanation for this behavior, but could not find any. I was reading about defining user controls, journal in Navigation Service, Data Context, and keeping alive pages when using Frames, but found nothing about user controls magically cloning their values to other controls.

I understand I could miss something simple or I defined all my user controls wrongly, but... this is not a behavior I would expect from a user control created in the simplest possible way.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me and answer my questions:

- why is this happening? Is it a bug in WPF itself?
- is this possible to create "safe" user control without necessarily using binding its values to an external source - and how to do it properly?

Sorry if I did not provide all the required information, but I don't know which information will be valuable as it seems to be a vague problem. I will try to answer any questions.

Comment: Pages can retain state, it's one of their selling points. They don't do so in the page exactly though unless keep alive is set to true. I suspect this behaviour is related. Pages are a bad idea unless you're building a wizard like flow where the user may go back and forth filling in several views for one purpose.

Comment: If you set KeepAlive="True" on your pages.  Does it still copy state or does the problem disappear?

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for the response. Yes, KeepAlive = "True" does help in both projects. It does make sense, as it forces to keep in memory states of all the elements on the Page. (Although I'm surprised because I read your post in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844836/how-are-wpf-pages-held-in-memory and as I understand it - when using Frames, attribute "KeepAlive" is set to "True" by default, so why setting it manually to "True" makes a difference?)

Comment: Setting KeepAlive = "True" seems to be an answer, but what if I don't want to keep the page alive? As you wrote, keeping alive many pages will be a memory hog. Do you know why is this 'cloning thing' even happening?
Here is the whole simple project that reproduces the bug, if you want to check it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cieM2tQ33l0sVeKJMA5uIaxeJvMkSsJQ/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discovered workaround is to bind values of controls to properties in code behind (it solves the problem) - at least visually.

Answer (score 0):

It's the frame journal which stores state for pages which have been shown.

If you don't go back to the previous page in your real app you could do:

```
 NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()
```

After you navigate.

That should remove whatever the journal just got.

You could also try giving things explicit X:Name and see if that allows the journal mechanism to differentiate.

Personally, I avoid frames and pages and I suggest you might consider using contentpresenter and usercontrols instead. I prefer viewmodel first navigation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do navigate back to the previous page in my app and I can't use RemoveBackEntry(). Giving things explicit x:Name is not working (it was the first thing I did after finding this bug). Anyway, thank you for your time.